# How can i avoid Android spellchecking my *Button*?

Tags: android, button

I have a very simple button, which should look somewhat like this:

[image: button design]

However, Android sometimes decides to spellcheck it, so it looks like this:

[image: button irl]

I would like to avoid that, but i have no idea where to start?
This behavior is not reproducible 100% of the time, and newer devices seem to show this error less often, or on less buttons (i'm using this style throughout my app)

Button in xml:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/previousButton"
    style="@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton.Link"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/parental_leave_summary_back"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_small"
    app:iconGravity="textStart"
    />
```

Styles:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton.Link">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.12</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button.TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:capitalize">none</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">@dimen/distance_100</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.14</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with following code. Just paste it in layout of Button.

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: This looks like its working, thanks! Could you (try to) explain why this works / is needed?

Comment: @m.reiter it basically tells the keyboard to not show dictionary based suggestions, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)